# BATCH test variable

Tags: batch-file, variables

I have this:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %%N in ('type C:\outputfile2.txt" ^| find /i "Fichier"') do (set $niveau=%%N')
```

I want `if !$niveau! equal to "B" set $niveau=1 else set $niveau=2`

I try brackets, simple quote, double, equal to test variable value but always the syntax is not correct.

Comment: Note parentheses and quotes: `if "%%N" EQU "B" (set $niveau=1) else set $niveau=2`

Comment: Perfect! thanks a lot

Comment: It isn't clear to me if this is the best way of achieving what you want, can you provide an example of the lines from `outputfile2.txt` and explain if you only want `$niveau` `set`ting if `Fichier` is found or if you want to `set` a value based upon some other criteria. Also you can improve your command a little by not `|`ing the result of `type` to `find`: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %%N in ('Find /I "Fichier"^<"C:\outputfile2.txt"') do if "%%N"=="B" (set $niveau=1) else set $niveau=2`.

Comment: I just wanted to parse a line to grab a letter at the specific position in the line and "transform" it to 1 if the letter was B in my final "re-organized" file or to 2 if it was another letter. The answer form JosefZ is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks